# Regex in JSX file not working, trying to remove the quotation marks "" that return around name

Tags: regex, reactjs, typescript, validation, jsx

```
    const Json = ({ data }: any) => <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</pre>;
    let profileName = <Json data={account.name.replace(/\"/g, '')}/>
```

not used to using regex, but I am trying to remove all instances of ""
When I use that regex with a normal hardcoded string of a name it works, why doesn't it work with this one?

Comment: If you don't what the quotes why JSON.stringify it?

Comment: You're right, just returning data fixed my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

what'up?

The `JSON.stringify()` automatically put quotes!

Remove it!

I hope to help!